# Delete first two lines of file with ruby

Tags: ruby

My script reads in large text files and grabs the first page with a regex. I need to remove the first two lines of each first page or change the regex to match 1 line after the ==Page 1== string. I include the entire script here because I've been asked to in past questions and because I'm new to ruby and don't always know how integrate snippets as answers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU
require 'fileutils'

source = File.open('list.txt')
source.readlines.each do |line|
  line.strip!
  if File.exists? line
    file = File.open(line)
  end

  text = (File.read(line))
  match = text.match(/==Page 1(.*)==Page 2==/m)
  puts match
end
```

Comment: Could you express what you want the code to do? It looks for me like that: I want to delete the first 2 lines on each file that is included in a list stored in another file. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry -- edited. You're correct, want to delete the first two lines of each file in my list.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I hope I have found Your problem :-) _(notifying through comment, because I do not know whether askers are notified about answer updates)_

Answer (score 3):

Now, when You have updated your question, I had to delete a big part of so good answer :-)

I guess the main point of your problem was that you wanted to use `match[1]` instead of `match`. The object returned by `Regexp.match` method (`MatchData`) can be treated like an array, which holds the whole matched string as the first element, and each subquery in the following elements. So, in your case the variable `match` *(and `match[0]`)* is the whole matched string *(together with '==Page..==' marks)*, but you wanted just the first subexpression which is hidden in `match[1]`.

---

Now about other, minor problems I sense in your code. Please, don't be offended in case you already know what I say, but maybe others will profit from the warnings.

The **first** part of your code (`if File.exists? line`) was checking whether the file exists, but your code just opened the file (without closing it!) and still was trying to open the file few lines later.

You may use this line instead:

```
next unless File.exists? line
```

The **second** thing is that the program should be prepared to handle the situation when the file has no page marks, so it does not match the pattern. *(The variable `match` would then be `nil`)*

The **third** suggestion is that a little more complicated pattern might be used. The current one (`/==Page 1==(.*)==Page 2==/m`) would return the page content with the End-Of-Line mark as the first character. If you use this pattern:

```
/==Page 1==\s*\n(.*)==Page 2==/m
```

then the subexpression will not contain the white spaces placed in the same line as the '==Page 1==` text. And if you use this pattern:

```
/==Page 1==\s*\n(.*\n)==Page 2==/m
```

then you will be sure that the '==Page 2==' mark starts from the beginning of the line.

And the **fourth** issue is that very often programmers *(sometimes including me, of course)* tend to forget about closing the file after they opened it. In your case you have opened the 'source' file, but in the code there was no `source.close` statement after the loop. The most secure way of handling files is by passing a block to the `File.open` method, so You might use the following form of the first lines of your program:

```
File.open('list.txt') do |source|
  source.readlines.each do |line|
```

...but in this case it would be cleaner to write just:

```
File.readlines('list.txt').each do |line|
```

Taking it all together, the code might look like this *(I changed the variable `line` to `fname` for better code readability)*:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU
require 'fileutils'

File.readlines('list.txt').each do |fname|
  fname.strip!
  next unless File.exists? fname

  text = File.read(fname)
  if match = text.match(/==Page 1==\s*\n(.*\n)==Page 2==/m)
    # The whole 'page' (String):
    puts match[1].inspect
    # The 'page' without the first two lines:
    # (in case you really wanted to delete lines):
    puts match[1].split("\n")[2..-1].inspect
  else
    # What to do if the file does not match the pattern?
    raise "The file #{fname} does NOT include the page separators."
  end
end
```